# Junit not working with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot

I am trying to test my repository using Spring-boot.

I followed http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

My Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class NotificationRepositoryTest {

    @Inject
    NotificationRepository notificationRepository;

    @Test
    public void notificationRepositoryTest()
    {
       //some logic
    }
}
```

Application.java:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.mycompany.notification.processor.service"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ImportResource({
        "classpath:integration-context.xml", "classpath:launch-context.xml", "classpath:applicationContext-NotificationProcessorService.xml"
})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.mycompany.notification.processor.service.dao"})
//@Import({ ServletConfiguration.class, WebappConfiguration.class })
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'http://artifactory/artifactory/libs-release-local' }
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone/' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.0.RELEASE")
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
    apply plugin: 'war'

    war {
        baseName = 'notification-processor-service'
        version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    jar {
        baseName = 'notification-processor-service'
        version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }

    ext {
        springIntegrationKafkaVersion = '1.0.0.M2'
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://artifactory/artifactory/libs-release-local' }
        maven { url 'http://artifactory/artifactory/resin-hessian' }
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/public'
        }
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone/' }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
        compile("com.mycompany.core:infra-messaging-framework:0.0.14")
                {
                    exclude module: 'org.springframework:spring-asm'
                    exclude module: 'spring-webmvc'
                    exclude module: 'org.springframework:spring-oxm'
                    exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
                }
        compile("com.mycompany.services.configuration:ConfigurationManager:2.0.11")
                {
                    exclude module: 'org.springframework:spring-asm'
                    exclude module: 'spring-webmvc'
                    exclude module: 'org.springframework:spring-oxm'
                    exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
                }
        compile("com.caucho:resin-hessian:4.0.23")
        compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.0.RELEASE')
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:1.2.0.RELEASE")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
        compile("javax.inject:javax.inject:1")
        compile('org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-manager:1.3.0.RELEASE') {
            exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
        }

        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.2.0.RELEASE')

    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '1.11'
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot load an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration or @ContextHierarchy.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:57)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 23 more
```

Any idea what am I missing?

thank you.

Comment: Do you really sure that this StackTrace is related to that `NotificationRepositoryTest`? Looks like some of your test classes is just marked with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and when you run all your tests from IDEA you see such an Exception. I have enough tests with `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`, so your case does not make sence for me if show just only correct Spring Boot test class

Comment: Thats the only test case I Have. I dont have any other @RunWith in my project than this class

Comment: Please, take a look to the IDEA dependencies for project and be sure that there is no an old Spring Test version

Comment: Going by the names of those imports, I would have to guess that some of those imported XML configs are not setting up their contexts correctly. Given that it's a Spring Boot app, it'w quite likely that none of them should be defining any kind of  context. I would recommend trying the test with all of those imports removed. Also, you shouldn't need `@EnableJpaRepositories`, although that may just be an artifact of your project structure, which we can't see.

Comment: I uploaded my project to github. check my junit class here. mybe it will be easier to nail this down. https://github.com/IdanFridman/NotificationProcessorService/blob/master/src/test/com/notification/processor/service/repository/NotificationRepositoryTest.java   thank you.

Comment: The code doesn't compile. The `com.notification.processor.service.dao.NotificationRepository` class appears to be missing. The test code also needs to be moved to `src/test/java` (it's currently in `src/test`).

Comment: you were right:  The test code also needs to be moved to src/test/java. answer it and ill mark your answer.